# Zero width or height versus visible property in QML

Tags: qt, qml

Does setting an component's `width` or `height` to zero has the same effect as setting its `visible` property to `false`?

An example use-case:

I have an item, which slides into the window. The sliding happens by animating its height from `0` to `x` and when I dismiss this item from `x` to `0`. Don't want to go in depth why I am not animating the position of the item instead. When the item has 0 height, should I set its `visible` property to `false` or it doesn't make any difference?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Not really, unless you clip. And it is better to avoid clipping as much as possible.

An `Item` with zero size will still have its children visible.

Whereas setting visible to false will hide the entire object tree.

In your particular case it seems like it doesn't matter as long as it doesn't cause you to have unwanted visible leftovers. You certainly do not want to have a binding such as `visible: height` as that would needlessly execute on every step of the animation.

Just to be on the safe side, you can install handlers on the animation to toggle visibility:

```
// in the animation
onStarted: if (!item.height) item.visible = true // show if start at 0
onStopped: if (!item.height) item.visible = false // hide if end at 0
```

This will avoid the continuous reevaluations you'd get if you bind visibility to height directly, but will still ensure visibility on before your object begins expanding and off after it has finished contracting.

Comment: Yes, in my case the children are 0 height as well. Thanks for the clarification and pointing out the binding hell to the `visible` property.

Comment: Well, I wouldn't call it hell, but it is overhead that you can avoid, so why not?

Comment: I would still bind `visible` to `height` but guard the evaluation of this binding by `&&` it with some conditions in which *I know that it won't change*. QML seems to be pretty intelligent on this one. Besides ensuring that the whole object tree will be hidden, you add clarity to your interface on *where to query the visiblitity*. If another programmer would want to know it, he'd need to query `visible`, `opacity`, `dimensions` and possibly the object tree to determine whether the Item is indeed visible. I would consider setting `visible` to a correct value, to be good practice.

Comment: @derM it would be better to use a timer and simply turn visibility off after the animation has ended rather than have the binding reevaluated. Or use `finished` and count on the animation not being interrupted  abnormally. You cannot really guard the evaluation, as the `&&` itself will need evaluation. Besides it doesn't get any faster than `visible: height` to begin with.

Answer (score 2):

As *dtech* already pointed out, the dimensions of the root node of a component do not automatically represent the dimensions of the underlying object tree. As an example take this:

```
Item {
    id: root
    Text {
        id: txt
        text: 'some text produces implicit width'
    }
}
```

In this example the text of `txt` will be shown, though the dimensions of `root` are `width: 0; height: 0`.
As *dtech* already mentioned, you might set `clip` to `true`, but this is not advisable, as then it would be passed to the renderer, which renders the `Item` and its tree and finally applies clipping to it - in a seperate batch.

If you have something like that:

```
Item {
    Rectangle {
        anchors.fill: parent
        color: 'red'
    }
}
```

The renderer would do nothing extra when rendering, as it could be processed in the same batch as the rest. However as a developer it is hard to tell, whether something is visible when the size is set to `0` or not. Therefore it is adivsable to always set `visible` properly.

We might simply set

```
visible: width > 0 && height > 0 && opacity > 0
```

which works fine, as long as we don't animate on any of those properties or change them frequently. At least for animations we might have good knowledge, when the any of those properties *might* become `0` and use this information to reduce the amount of evaluations.

The nice thing about QML is, that the logical expression is evaluated from the left to the right, which means in our last example:

- If `width === 0` and `height` changes, it wont trigger reevaluation
- If `height === 0` and `width` changes, each change triggers reevaluation.

This means, we need to put the most stable condition first. This might be our *information about when any of those values might change*. I propose, using the `animation.running` property, to prevent reevaluation of the binding, while the animation is running.

Let's take a more complete example: Upon click, this `Rectangle` will shrink from `width: 800` to `width: 0` - which shall set it invisible.

Or three additional properties `binding1, binding2, binding3` are bound to expressions, that we might use to set `visible`. When ever a particular part of the binding is reeavluated, we log this.

```
Rectangle {
    id: rect
    color: 'red'
    width: 800
    height: 600

    NumberAnimation {
        id: ani1
        target: rect
        property: 'width'
        from: 800
        to: 0
        duration: 3000
    }
}
MouseArea {
    anchors.fill: parent
    onClicked: ani1.running = true
}

property bool binding1: {console.log("1", !rect.width); return !rect.width}
property bool binding2: {!ani1.running && (function() { console.log("2", !rect.width); return !rect.width })()}
property bool binding3: {(function() { console.log("3", !rect.width); return !rect.width })() && !ani1.running}

// equivalent, stripped of the logging:
// property bool binding1: !rect.width
// property bool binding2: !ani1.running && !rect.width
// property bool binding3: !rect.width && !ani1.running
```

As we can see, `binding1` is constantly reevaluated, when ever the width changes. This is not desirable.
We can see, that `binding2` is only evaluated once at creation, and whenever `ani` stops running.
In `binding3` we have it the other way around and we first evaluate the `width`, and then whether the `ani` is running. This means, we have a reevaluation whenever the `width` is changing.

We could also use the signal handlers `ani.onStarted` and `ani.onStopped` and explicitly set the visiblity then, but that would not be *declarative* and QML encourages you to always strive to stay declarativ.

Comment: What if the items which I animate are delegates of a `ListView` and this `ListView` is wrapped in an `Item` and I would like to set this `Item`'s `visible` property to false if all of the delegates within the `ListView` aren't visible, aka their `visible` property is `false`. Do I just simply loop through the `children` property of the `ListView` and check if any of them has `visible = true`? Sounds a bit hacky.

Comment: What I tend to do is have the delegate wrapped in a loader, and rather than simply hiding delegates, they are unloaded from memory for hidden objects. The loader is set to size to the item or to 0x0 if it is unloaded. There would be no tangible benefit to hide a list view all of whose delegates are loaders with zero size, as it will have no visible representation whatsoever, there is nothing to gain from hiding that, not memory not cpu cycles, but there is gain to be had from unloading hidden stuff by using a loader. So if efficiency is priority, that's the way to go.

Comment: Uhg, that is a complicated matter. First, you need to have a role in the model that somewhat stores the visiblity. You could use the models signals to count how many of the items fulfill the visibility condition (e.g. dataChanged, counting up and down). You could also use a `QSortFilterProxyModel` to filter on that condition and use the `count` property of this. If you don't need the `delegate` for that entry, use it in the `ListView`. This will do the unloading automatically. If you need the delegate (e.g. because of a `Timer`) use the original model. Then unload the visual with a `Loader`.

Comment: If you have hundreds of invisible items between two visible ones that has various implications: **1.** the guess for the total size of the contentItem of the `ListView` will be off. **2.** When scrolling, all of them will be created. So, not having them *at all* by filtering them with the `QSortFilterProxyModel` will save you tons of creations and destructions of unnecessary items. If there are important (invisible) parts of the delegates, you might have messed up anyway, as you can't guarantee their existence (when the Items would be out of view). Put them in a seperate `Instantiator`.